# Orbit and stabaliser of $2\times2 * 2\times1$ matrices

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

I have the group action of matrix multiplication, meaning:

$g((x,y))=\begin{pmatrix}a&0\\0&b\end{pmatrix}$$ \begin{pmatrix}x\\ y\end{pmatrix}$

$G=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}a&0\\0&b\end{pmatrix}:a,b\in\mathbb{R} - \{0\} \right\} g=\begin{pmatrix}a&0\\0&b\end{pmatrix}\in G$ and $X=\{(x,y):x,y\in\mathbb{R}\}$

I want to work out orbits and stabilizer.

I have only done this with permutation groups, so I have no idea how to do this:

Definition of orbit $orb((x,y))=\{g((x,y)):g\in G\}$

So I have $org((x,y))$ equalling the identity matrix?

$stab((x,y))=\{g\in G:g((x,y))=(x,y)\}$

That makes $stab((x,y))$ look like the identity though? Which am I misunderstanding?

Comment: You should edit your post to specify what $G$ is. I'm assuming it the set of all invertible real diagonal $2 \times 2$ matrices?

Comment: $orb((x,y))$ is a subset of $X$, not a subset of $G$. Your computation of the stabilizer is correct, though.

Comment: @Bungo Sorry, edited

Comment: Hint for the orbits: $(0,0)$ is clearly its own orbit. What can you say about the orbits of $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$?

Comment: @Bungo I am having trouble reading the definition. The orbit of $x$ equals the set of every group action that, does what? In a finite set I just looked at a permutation group, e.g. $(12345)$ then the orbit of $1$ = $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$

Comment: @Bungo Is the orbit of $x$ the set of all applications of the group action $g(x)$?

Comment: @Algebra: the orbit of $(x,y)$ is the set of all $(a,b)$ such that $(a,b) = g(x,y)$ for some element of $g$. In other words, it is the set of all vectors that can be "reached" from $(x,y)$ by the group action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The orbit of a vector $(x,y) \in X$ is the set of all $(a,b) \in X$ that can be "reached" by the group action. In other words, the orbit of $(x,y)$ is the set of all $(a,b)$ such that $(a,b) = g(x,y)$ for some $g\in G$.

The stabilizer of a vector $(x,y) \in X$ is the set (which turns out to be a subgroup) of all $g \in G$ such that $g(x,y) = (x,y)$.

Your problem can be naturally divided into four cases.

**Case 1**: $x = y = 0$.

Since $g(0,0) = (0,0)$ for every $g \in G$, the orbit of $(0,0)$ is just the singleton $\{(0,0)\}$.

The stabilizer of $(0,0)$ is the set of all $g\in G$ such that $g(0,0) = (0,0)$. Since this is true for any $g\in G$, the stabilizer of $(0,0)$ is the entire group $G$.

**Case 2**: $x = 0, y \neq 0$

Since 
$$\begin{pmatrix}
a & 0 \\
0 & b \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
y \\
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
by \\
\end{pmatrix}$$
and $b$ is any nonzero real number, the orbit of any vector of the form $(0,y)$ (where $y \neq 0$) is the set of *all* vectors of the form $(0,z)$ where $z$ is any nonzero number.

The stabilizer of such an vector $(0,y)$ is the set of all $\begin{pmatrix}
a & 0 \\
0 & b \\
\end{pmatrix}$ such that
$$\begin{pmatrix}
a & 0 \\
0 & b \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
y \\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
y \\
\end{pmatrix}$$
This forces $b=1$, but $a$ can be anything. So the stabilizer of $(0,y)$ is the set of all matrices in $G$ of the form $$\begin{pmatrix}
a & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$
You can easily check that this set is indeed a subgroup of $G$, as is any stabilizer.
I'll let you work out the details of the other two cases, which are:

**Case 3**: $x \neq 0, y = 0$

and

**Case 4**: $x \neq 0, y \neq 0$

Two "sanity checks" you can use once you think you have a solution:

1. The orbits *partition* the set $X$. In other words, every element of $X$ belongs to exactly one orbit.
2. The stabilizer of each element of $X$ is a subgroup of $G$.

One more note: In general it's possible for different elements of $X$ to have the same stabilizer. Elements that are in the same orbit do not necessarily have the same stabilizer, and elements in different orbits can have the same stabilizer.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is probably the best answer I have seen on MSE.

Comment: @Algebra: I'm glad it was helpful :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you write out the group action as $$g * \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & b \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} ax \\ by \end{pmatrix}$$

For the stabilizer, we look for elements $g \in G$ such that $$g * \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}$$ This means that we are looking for $a$ and $b$ such that $ax = x$ and $bx = x$. If $x$ is nonzero, then we must have that $a = 1$, and similarly nonzero $y$ implies that our desired $b$ equals $1$. If $x =0$, then we can choose any nonzero $a$ (as $ax = a \cdot 0 = 0$ for each nonzero $a$), and if $y = 0$, we can choose any value of $b$. To summarize this, considering arbitrary nonzero $x$ and $y$, we have

$$\mathrm{stab}_{G}\left( \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} \right) = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \right\}, \: \: \mathrm{stab}_{G}\left( \begin{pmatrix} x \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \right) = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & b \end{pmatrix} \bigg| b \in \mathbb{R} - \{0\} \right\}$$ $$\mathrm{stab}_{G}\left( \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ y \end{pmatrix} \right) = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\bigg| a \in \mathbb{R} - 0 \right\}, \:\mathrm{stab}_{G}\left( \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \right) = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & b \end{pmatrix} \bigg|\: a,b \in \mathbb{R} - 0 \right\}$$

Now, the orbit is the set of elements $\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ y_1 \end{pmatrix}$ such that there exists $g \in G$ for which $$ g * \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ y_1 \end{pmatrix}$$ Because $a$ and $b$ can be any nonzero real number, we then have that $$\mathrm{orb}_{G} \left( \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} \right) = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} ax \\ by \end{pmatrix} \bigg| \: a,b \in \mathbb{R} - \{0\} \right\}$$

Comment: If $y = 0$ then $(x,y)$ is stabilized by matrices other than the identity. Similarly if $x=0$. If both are zero, then $(0,0)$ is stabilized by the entire group.

Comment: Whoops. Thanks for pointing this out, I have edited the post to correct my mistake.

Comment: Thank you Daniel, this helped my understanding :).